# SQL convert date nvarchar datatype to float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an excel file that contains a column date, in the excel it is formatted as date.

It is included in a SQL database, unfortunately I have no influence on the procedure.

In the SQL database the following command is executed:

```
WHEN YEAR(CAST(CAST(REPLACE(redatum, ',', '.') AS float) - 2 AS datetime) AS date)) <> @YEAR
     THEN DATEFROMPARTS(@YEAR, 12, 31) 
     ELSE CAST(CAST(REPLACE(redatum, ',', '.') AS float) - 2 AS datetime) AS date) 
END redatum
```

And I get the following error message when I run it.

> Error converting nvarchar datatype to float.

Are there any tips on how to fix this error?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by `It is included in a SQL database` ?

Comment: As we can't peek into your database, we have no idea what sort of values `redatum` contains. Obviously somewhere something ends up invalid. Use `TRY_CAST`/`TRY_CONVERT` to find what.

Comment: Why are you trying to store a `date` as a float in the first place, and then why are you converting it to a date and time data time? This sounds severely flawed; your conversion process is `nvarchar`->`float`->`datetime`->`date`.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but one of the reasons you are getting errors is when converting to float. if you have NULL or an EMPTY string then the system won't know what to do with the data so it will throw an exception.

Comment: @Demeteor: in this case, neither empty strings nor `NULL` are a problem, in the sense that they will not cause errors. The former gives `1899-12-30`, the latter `NULL`. T-SQL's rules for conversion are arcane.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I really agree on the arcane part. but back on the subject, I thought that might be the case since trying to convert either NULL decimals or Floats. usually results in problems in one way or another. but it seems its not the case

Comment: “In Excel it is formatted as a date” doesn’t make it a valid date. Excel will let me enter the string `13/13/2022` which sure looks like a date but it’s not. The error is happening because at least one of the strings coming from Excel does not represent a valid date. That said, I agree with Larnu, I have no idea why you’re going through all these conversion steps (float? really?). If it’s a valid date in Excel, just `TRY_CONVERT(date, column, style_number)`. The ones that are invalid will yield NULL.